# CSS Keyframe Animation Similar to Stop Motion

Tags: css, css-animations

I need to use keyframe animations to move the background-position of a sprite sheet. However, I do not want animations, I want a hard frame by frame look, similar to a gif.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you can achieve this more beautifully, with JavaScript:

```css
@-webkit-keyframes sprite {
  0%    { background-position: 0px 0px; }
  25%   { background-position: 0px 0px; }
  25.1% { background-position: -200px 0px; }
  50%   { background-position: -200px 0px; }
  50.1% { background-position: -400px 0px; }
  75%   { background-position: -400px 0px; }
  75.1% { background-position: -400px -200px; }
  99.9% { background-position: -400px -200px; }
  100%  { background-position: 0px 0px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes sprite {
  0%    { background-position: 0px 0px; }
  25%   { background-position: 0px 0px; }
  25.1% { background-position: -200px 0px; }
  50%   { background-position: -200px 0px; }
  50.1% { background-position: -400px 0px; }
  75%   { background-position: -400px 0px; }
  75.1% { background-position: -400px -200px; }
  99.9% { background-position: -400px -200px; }
  100%  { background-position: 0px 0px; }
}

@-o-keyframes sprite {
  0%    { background-position: 0px 0px; }
  25%   { background-position: 0px 0px; }
  25.1% { background-position: -200px 0px; }
  50%   { background-position: -200px 0px; }
  50.1% { background-position: -400px 0px; }
  75%   { background-position: -400px 0px; }
  75.1% { background-position: -400px -200px; }
  99.9% { background-position: -400px -200px; }
  100%  { background-position: 0px 0px; }
}

@keyframes sprite {
  0%    { background-position: 0px 0px; }
  25%   { background-position: 0px 0px; }
  25.1% { background-position: -200px 0px; }
  50%   { background-position: -200px 0px; }
  50.1% { background-position: -400px 0px; }
  75%   { background-position: -400px 0px; }
  75.1% { background-position: -400px -200px; }
  99.9% { background-position: -400px -200px; }
  100%  { background-position: 0px 0px; }
}
    
div.image {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwOaY.jpg');
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-animation: 5s sprite infinite;
  -moz-animation: 5s sprite infinite;
  -o-animation: 5s sprite infinite;
  animation: 5s sprite infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class='image'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much @drinchev, this is just what I was looking for. Thank you for providing a Demo as well.

Answer (score 5):

The key is CSS timing-function. The stop-motion frames correspond to the steps function.

```
animation-timing-function: steps(n);
```

[code example: css stop-motion animation](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/css-animation-art/d6Y83Sv8M4g/yyTAG7oK160J)

[Demo](https://webchain.oreilly.tw/boohover/csslabs/properties/css-animate-effect-1.html#stop-motion-animation)

Comment: It's generally a good idea to have more than just links in your answer, as if the linked sites go down or change address, your answer will become useless. While links are good for sourcing information, it's always a good idea to also write out the relevant information.

Comment: @qaphla Thanks for your advice, I know what you concern. However, the links above are my own website and forum, and the code is also written by myself.

Comment: That may be the case, but that still doesn't guarantee that they will outlast Stack Overflow. As such, even if you just copy the information directly, it's more helpful to have it in your answer.

Comment: This method works. Jsbin modified from drinchev's answer: http://jsbin.com/nipuxukeka/3/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to use keyframed animation only, one idea that comes to my head is to do:

```
@keyframes youranim {
    0%     { top: 0px;   }
    24.99% { top: 0px;   }
    25%    { top: 200px; }
    49.99% { top: 200px; }
    50%    { top: 400px; }
    74.99% { top: 400px; }
    75%    { top: 600px; } /* and so on... */
}
```

I read that decimal values are ok for CSS3 keyframes.